# What is the writer thinking about here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading one of the stories in an article from 1843 Magazine. The title of the article is "Suffering from shortages? How to survive without puppies, fake tan or IKEA." The title of this story is "No chips, no problem: why old video games are better than new ones".

> My mother and father believed that video games would ruin my life.
> Which is something to ***think about*** when I’m at my writing desk
> and look over my left shoulder to a wall of 446 video games, arranged
> like paperbacks on 34 shelves in a cabinet six-feet wide by
> five-and-a-half-feet tall.

I know "think about" means to "reflect on or to ruminate over", but I am not sure whether the writer here means to think about if video games have ruined his life or not.

Comment: Don't take the words too literally. He could probably just as easily have written *...which is something **to bear in mind***, or even ***...be aware of***. It's unlikely he always thinks that deeply (ruminates over) what his parents said years ago, every time he sits at his desk surrounded by game cartridges.

Comment: This writer is using irony or sarcasm here. Their parents said that video games would ruin their life, but the writer shows us that they are still successful even though they clearly love video games. The phrase "think about" is a subtle prompt for the reader to think about how these parts relate

Answer (score 1):

He thinks about what goes before: that fact that his parents *believed* something.

The phrase introduces the reader to the idea that the parents' belief, while maybe justified *at the time*, seems to have been proven unwarranted.
And indeed, what follows is a description of the writer being surrounded by video-games, but implying that the writer's life has not exactly been ruined by them.

This is a commonly used idiomatic construct:

> My grandparents believed computers would never become popular. That is something to think about when I realize that now I am surrounded by hundreds of them: my pc's, my laptop, my phone, my car, my watch, my TV, and more, are arguably everyday occurrences of computers.

The *implied* message here is: even just two generations ago people didn't believe computers would become popular, but boy, were they wrong!